# Floating Textfields Yahoo Range Seek Bar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-seekbar

first i was using the Range Seek Bar from 
https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar

but ofcourse of more funktions etc. i tried the forked Version from 
https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar

The Sample Project is running nice on my device but the problem is, if i try to integrate the libary in my existing app.

I edited my gradle.build

```
compile 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
```

and everything runs without some Errors

But the problem for me is know, that i cant get the Seekbar same as in the Sampleproject.
In this one they have "Floating Textfields" over the Seekbar, so where you can see, whats your actual Point on the Seekbar.
An Other thing is, that the buttons are way bigger on the example project then on my App.

In the layout and MainActivity files from the Sample Project is nothing special, so i rly dont know where to search for the changes.

Would be rly nice if someone of you could help me fix the little problem.